# Concatenate a string to display group name in group footer.

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I'm trying to do a reset for this formula I tried either =0 or ="" but don't seem to reset the formula based on the formula. 
I have 2 Groupings 
Group 1 Check #
Group 2 Name
 I want to concatenate Group 2 Name in the Group footer 2
then reset based on Group 1 Check # if it has changed.

Formula 1 ( placed in Group header )

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
stringvar array arr;
numbervar i;
if not({Customer.Name} in arr) then
(
i := i + 1;
redim preserve arr[i];
arr[i] := {Customer.Name};
);
arr[i]
```

Formula 2 (Placed in the group footer)

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
stringvar array arr;
stringvar fin;
numbervar j;
for j := 1 to ubound(arr) do
fin := fin + arr[j] + ", ";
left(fin,len(fin)-2);
```

Comment: where is the reset part in your question?

Comment: The reset I tried is the follow:            Whileprintingrecords; Stringvar Array arr:= ""; numbervar i :=0; Stringvar fin:=0; numbervar j:=0  I placed it on the group header and did not reset the array or output of the formula not including the previous group name if the check number changed.

Comment: if you have place in group header 1 then this should work... if you have place in group header 2 then there can be issue. also where is condition to check in reset